# Search in multiple collections with mongoose (MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have several collections with the same structure. Like this:

```
const generalSchemaObject = {
    type: String,
    id: String
}

const oneType = new Schema(generalSchemaObject);
const secondType = new Schema(generalSchemaObject);
const thirdType = new Schema(generalSchemaObject);
```

How can I search in these collections at once? For example, I need to find any documents with some id, how I can do that at one query?

I would like to build some "parent" object, but I don't know how.
And I want to use it like this:
`parentObject.find({id: '123'})`

Can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Why r u creating 3 collections here?? You can have it in 1 collections..

Comment: You can't do that with one query, because you can't do that with MongoDB in general. So you're going to have to run three queries, one for each collection/model, and combine the results in your code.

Comment: I do not believe that you can search multiple collections in MongoDB using one query. However, aggregation might be an option